# CocoaPods dependency only on debug/release build

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using a pod as an internal library for my project.

I want to have some pods included only on release/debug builds, like Reveal/Sparkinspector.

Is there any way to define `podspec` dependencies depending on the currently selected build configuration (build/release)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

With the recent release it's officially available now: http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.34/

Use

```
pod 'Lookback', :configurations => ['Debug']
```

Comment: Unfortunately - it does not work for me at least for cocoapods v.1.11.2 - the executable contains symbols from cocoapod. checked by cmd: `nm` upd: I found task about my issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9658

Answer (score 0):

For anyone just finding this, this looks to be scheduled in the next release, per my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25653469/490180

Answer (score -6):

see the multiple targets section here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/A-Podfile

e.g.

```
target :debug do
    pod 'TestFlight'
end
```

Comment: That's not the same, the idea was to simply define different pods for release/debug configuration. As far as I am concerned it is possible in Xcode but Pods do not support build configurations yet.