# Cocoapods for development only

Tags: ios, xcode, dependency-management, cocoapods

Is there a way to use a dependency only in development? I don't want to ship the Reveal SDK :/

I'm searching for something similar to

```
#ifdef DEBUG
```

Can't find anything in the cocoapods docs.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? Looks like a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610551/cocoapods-dependency-only-on-debug-release-build

Comment: I'll cross-link to my answer here in that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's scheduled for next release. See here:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/731

Answer (score 1):

There is [an issue on the CocoaPods github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/731) that is discussing the ability to dynamically link a pod based on the selected build configuration, but there is currently no release that supports this feature. According to the maintainers, the feature will be released in the next version of CocoaPods.