# cocoapod with several configurations

Tags: ios, configuration, frameworks, cocoapods

I have two tags in my specs file, and i build manually the library in debug and release mode. 
Using cocoa pods with a private library like Flurry in debug and release, how can i say to get the library in debug or release configuration in the final project using cocoa pods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoapods dependency only on debug/release build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610551/cocoapods-dependency-only-on-debug-release-build)

Comment: i have two library files for example mylibd.a and mylib.a, and i want if i am in debug, use mylibd.a or if i am in release use mylib.a